# Implement Autocomplete with b:inputText

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I am trying to do an autocomplete input with bootsfaces but I can't create this component. How can I create this component and get the list from one method of my Bean? I tried with `typeahead-values` property but I can't get values.

```
<b:inputText
    placeholder=""
    id="autocomplete"
    typeahead="true"
    typeahead-values="#{Expedients.getExpedients2()}"
/>
```

- EDITED -

I managed to show the autocomplete (a conflict with jquery)
I see the problem now is that the elements of the list containing the array brackets.
The bean code is :

```
public List<String> getExpedients2() {
    init();
    List<String> n = new ArrayList<String>();
    n.add("test1");
    n.add("test2");
    return n;
}
```

And finally this adds me this code in xhtml.

```
<script>
<!--
$('.formulario_autocomplete').typeahead({hint:true,highlight:true,minLength:1},
{limit:5,name:'formulario_autocomplete_typeahead',source: 
BsF.substringMatcher(['[test1','test2]'])});
//-->
</script>
```

The result of the elements is : '[test1' and 'test2]'

How can solved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, that's something we, the BootsFaces team, should do something about it. It took me quite some time to spot the error. Actually, it's a very simple one: when I implemented the autocompletion feature, I assumed your bean returns a simple comma-separated string.

```
public List<String> getExpedients2() {
    init();
    String n = "";
    n += "test1";
    n += ",";
    n += "test2";
    return n;
}
```

This simple approach works well enough, but I agree with you we should also support lists and arrays. I've opened [issue 532](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/532) on our BootsFaces bug tracker.

**Update**:
As it turns out, I managed to fix the bug in a few minutes. The new feature is going to be part of BootsFaces 1.0, which we plan to publish by next month (November 2016). You can test it even earlier by following the instructions at https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/369.